# Android How to package as API

Tags: android, sdk

I am working on providing SDK support for another apps by opening my app UI elements into another app. Its like having Facebook SDK integrated with other apps where one when click on "Login with Facebook" facebook UI comes up. Other apps like Uber has its own SDK
How can I achieve it? One option is to have .jar/.aar file packaged. Or Deep linking works well? Please also suggest some documentation which can help me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can create **Android Library**

[image]

One of the best tutorial is [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html)

to get the resource from your library project see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) link.

ex:

`R.id.image` would be:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("image", "id", "com.library.package");
```

Comment: My concern is that Jar file prepared by Gradle in Android Studio doesn't prepare files other than Java class files. I am unable to get Drawables, XML Layouts, etc.

Comment: ok where do you add the resourse files in your library project ? in assets folder ?

Comment: Library projects cannot include raw assets. it means you have to add resourses in res/ directory folder